# What are the best tools for testing web services with REST protocol and JSON data format?

Tags: json, testing, rest

I am new to testing of REST web services with JSON data format.

I tried SOUPUI, but unfortunately doesn't support JSON request.

I am now using the Chrome plugin for my tests, but I think it's not appropriate for test automation of these type of applications.

Does anybody know which tools are OK for this purpose?

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [sqa.stackexchange.com](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

We're using [RestClient](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) for testing our Rest/JSON WebServices. It's very handy and easy to use

Comment: +1 for recommending good tool. We use this as a compliment to other tools we use.

Answer (score 5):

A nifty framework/library for testing REST with json is "rest-assured"
http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/

Inspired by BDD and Groovy ( but it's Java ) it makes it easy to test REST resources

```
given().
        param("key1", "value1").
        param("key2", "value2").
expect().
        body(containsString("OK")).
when().
        post("/somewhere");
```

And it's easy to work with JSON path

```
// Example with JsonPath
String json = get("/lotto").asString()
List<String> winnderIds = from(json).get("lotto.winners.winnerId");
```

Getting started is easy.
http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted

*Disclaimer*
*rest-assured is founded and managed by the Company I work for.*

Comment: +1 for recommending a really good, useful tool that perfectly fits to the problem at hand. I wasn't aware of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One such tool is [HttpMaster](http://www.httpmaster.net).

It's quite flexible regarding REST API testing and has good JSON/XML support. For advanced test scenarios, you can define response data validations and establish chains of multiple requests.
The only possible drawback is that it runs on Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

There are few plugins which can be added for SOAP UI so that Json files can be accessed.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation