# Best pratice for testing REST interfaces

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, rest, erlang

I'm writing a REST-full webapp and I'm looking for a good testing framework. The app is mostly writen in Erlang, but I would like to test the front-end of the app without relying on the erlang code.

Also integration with a js testframework would be desireable.

Comment: HtmlUnit and Selenium come to mind.

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the title you say you want to test REST interfaces.  In the text you said you wanted to test the "front end", which normally refers to a UI.  Which is it?  Which part are you looking to test?

Comment: @Cheeso: I mean the json generated for my ajax calls

Comment: maybe a duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151721/what-is-the-best-tools-for-testing-web-services-with-rest-protocol-and-json-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day, if you have minimal ruby knowledge, then i would recommend you use capybara+rails solution, it also allows testing javascript-rich sites, just use javascript-enabled test driver like selenium, here is short doc about using it with remote sites: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master#Calling_remote_servers

Also check out cucumber http://cukes.info/ which plays well with rails+capybara combo and also has erlang port